# python-requests give me diffrent response from what I see in the browser, Why?

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to get data from [this site](http://option.ime.co.ir/).

When I get data from the main url. I get an HTML file that contains structure but not the values.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='http://option.ime.co.ir/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

I find out that the site get values from

```
url1 = 'http://option.ime.co.ir/GetTime'
url2 =  'http://option.ime.co.ir/GetMarketData'
```

When I watch responses from those url in the browser. I see a JSON format response and time in a specific format.

but when I use requests to get the data it gives me same HTML that I get from `url`.

Do you know whats the reason? How should I get the responses that I see in the browser?

I check headers for all urls and I didn't find something special that I should send with my request.

Comment: How can you say that headers are not useful? This is all about headers' stuff.

Comment: Check whether User-Agent field is different, you can usually get different responses based on client type.

Comment: @Ujival I didn't say headers are not useful, I said  I can't find anything useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide the proper HTTP headers in the request. In my case, I was able to make it work using the following headers. Note that in my testing the HTTP response was a `200 OK` rather than a redirect to the root website (as when no HTTP headers were provided in the request).

Raw HTTP Request:

```
GET http://option.ime.co.ir/GetTime HTTP/1.1
Host: option.ime.co.ir
Referer: "http://option.ime.co.ir/"
Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
User-Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
```

This should give you the proper JSON response you need.

Comment: No, I try to add those http requests to my get request result is same as before. I use Postman extension and python both of them didn't give me JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You first connection using the browser is getting a 302 Redirection response (to the same url).

Then it is running some JS so the so the second request doesn't redirect anymore and gets the expected JSON.

It is a usual technique so other people don't use their API without permission.

Set the "preserve log" checkbox in dev. tools so you can see it by yourself.

Comment: Is there any way to get that data? I set the preserve log" checkbox but nothing changes.

Comment: Set preserve log and then refresh. you'll all the requests to the server. No, the server has same origin policy, so unless you use a proxy, there is no way to by pass it.